# Attirbutable risk from competing risks

Tags: cox-model, biostatistics, epidemiology, population-attributable-fraction

There are a number of ways to estimate attributable risk fractions from Cox regression and logistic regression. Does anyone know how to estimate attributable risk from a competing risks regression using subdistribution hazard ratios, with 95% confidence intervals?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/259694/28500) provides quick summary of the Fine-Gray subdistribution hazard approach to competing risks, with a link to further information. As @AdamO put it on that page:

> The intepretation of this subdistributional hazard function is the instantaneous risk of death from cause 1 given you are either still alive, or you've already died of something else. In effect, it averages across these two possibilities in such a way that a high risk of dying previously from other causes lowers your hazard for that specific failure.

According to the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) on competing risks provided with the R [`survival` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=survival), this approach to modeling competing risks:

> can be done as a two stage process: the first stage creates a special data set while the second fits a weighted coxph or survfit model to the data.

The special data set is a collection of data sets, one for each endpoint, formulated to meet the requirements of the Fine-Gray analysis. That package has a `finegray()` function to produce the data sets from the original survival data. Cox regressions with weights assigned by the `finegray()` function then provide the basis for hazard ratios, confidence intervals, and so forth for each endpoint. There is also a [`cmprsk` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cmprsk) for such analyses.

Before you proceed, however, make sure that you understand the limitations of this approach. As the competing risks vignette puts it on page 24:

> A weakness of the Fine-Gray approach is that since the two endpoints are modeled separately, the results do not have to be consistent.

And on page 25:

> The primary strength of the Fine-Gray model with respect to the Cox model approach is that if lifetime risk is a primary question, then the model has given us a simple and digestible answer to that question ... . This simplicity is not without a price, however, and these authors are not proponents of the approach. There are five issues.

Of which the first and perhaps most important is:

> 1. The attempt to capture a complex process as a single value is grasping for a simplicity that does not exist for many (perhaps most) data sets. The necessary assumptions in a multivariate Cox model of proportional hazards, linearity of continuous variables, and no interactions are strong ones. For the FG model these need to hold for a combined process — the mixture of transition rates to each endpoint — which turns out to be a more difficult barrier.

Comment: Thank you but attributable risk cannot be calculated directly from cmprsk package

Comment: @bvowe it might help for you to edit your question to provide more details and an example of the type of attributable risk calculation that you wish to perform for a Fine-Gray analysis. Do you mean risk of each type of event as a function of some type of exposure, or some relative risk of the two types of events?

Comment: thanks for your note i am hoping to estimate the percentage of the outcome that is attributable to a specific risk factor in the context of the competing risks models

Comment: @bvowe I don't use `cmprsk` and only included it as it seemed potentially useful. The `survival` package method for Fine-Gray produces separate datasets for each competing outcome, suitable for Cox regressions. So any method "to estimate attributable risk fractions from Cox regression" would seem to apply to that competing-risks approach. See pages 19-20 of the vignette linked in my answer for an example of such Cox regressions based on Fine-Gray analysis of a data set having 2 competing risks.